# Why does SharePoint Designer 2010 overwrite my SQLDataSource?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-designer

I have a SharePoint page that uses a SPSqlDataSource to get data from SQL Server. I noticed that an existing SharePoint page with similar function had much better performance, and it used a SqlDataSource.

I replaced the SPSqlDataSource with a SqlDataSource, saved my changes, tested the results, and found them superior to the SPSqlDataSouce. I closed SharePoint Designer, and then things seemed to slow a bit. I opened up my file and was surprised to find my updates had been overwritten, and the original SPSqlDataSouce there.

How did my changes get overwritten? How do I make my change persistent?

```
<SharePoint:SPSqlDataSource runat="server" AllowIntegratedSecurity="False" ConnectionString="Data Source=dbserver;
    User ID=XXXXX;
    Password=XXXXX;
    Initial Catalog=XXXXX;
    " ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE... " ID="BlueFolderPartsConnection1">
<SelectParameters>
<WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="AllParam" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="*" Name="AllParam">
</WebPartPages:DataFormParameter>
</SelectParameters>
</SharePoint:SPSqlDataSource>
```

I changed it to this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
    ID="BlueFolderPartsConnection1"
    runat="server" 
    __designer:commandsync="true" 
    ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
    ConnectionString="XXXXX;
    User ID=XXXXX;
    Password=XXXXX;
    Initial Catalog=XXXXX;
    " SelectCommand="SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE... ">
<SelectParameters>
<WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="AllParam" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="*" Name="AllParam">
</WebPartPages:DataFormParameter>
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

> __designer:commandsync="true"

Set this property to "false" or remove it from the tag altogether.